# Symfony / Doctrine : Query builder - filter on collection (ManyToMany relation)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have an Entity (Bla) which has a ManyToMany relation to another Entity (Foo).

Therefore, $Bla->getFoos() returns a collection of Foo.

I would like to make a query to get all the Bla entities that have a defined collection of Foos.

something like :

```
$itemArr=$this->entityManager->getRepository('App\Entity\Bla')->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->join('p.foos', 'foos', 'WITH', 'foos = :foos')
    ->setParameter('foos', $currentBla->getFoos())
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

NB: the collection item match must be exact. inclusion is not enough

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `WHERE IN` statement and delete `->join('p.foos', 'foos', 'WITH', 'foos = :foos')` :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
->where('p.foos in (:foos)')
->setParameter('foos', $foos)
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```